# Adding span tag in json translation string

Tags: json, reactjs, string, internationalization, language-translation

I have a react app with JP/EN language options. I handle our copies&texts in such format.

```
      <TopHeading>
        {t('landingTitle')}
      </TopHeading>
      <SubHeading>
        {t('landingCatchCopy')}
      </SubHeading>
```

Then manage the translation strings in json file like below

```
    "landingTitle": "Portfolio made easy.",
    "landingCatchCopy": "Creators must-have, without a hassle.",
```

Now, I would like to include `<span>` tag in desired part of the text so that I could put a line-break to fit the text in the viewers screen responsibly.

How could I achieve this? Any hint will be much appreciated!
Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load `HTML` tag then use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<TopHeading>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('landingTitle') }}></div>
</TopHeading>
<SubHeading>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t('landingCatchCopy') }}></div>
</SubHeading>
```

manage the translation strings in json file like below

```
"landingTitle": "Portfolio made easy.",
"landingCatchCopy": "<span>Creators must-have,</span><br/><span>without a hassle.</span>",
```

Hope this will work for you!